# <img /> tag is appears with strange white border when src set wrong

Tags: html, css, image, sass, browser

In angular project I have template with this html code

```
<div class="promotion-item-img-wrapper__fm"
            [ngClass]="{'image-loader__fm' : 
!promotionService?.details || promotionService?.details?.LoadFailed}">
<img
     class="promotion-item_image__fm"
     height="100%"
     width="100%"
     [cdnFromEnvironment]="true"
     [formatImgSrc]="((configService.isMobile$ | async) ?
                                          promotionService?.details?.MobileImage :
                                          promotionService.details?.DesktopImage) || ''"
     [alt]="promotionService?.details?.Title || ''"
     (load)="handleSuccessLoad(promotionService?.details)"
     (error)="handleLoadFail(promotionService?.details)"
/>
</div>
```

and scss styles for this part of code

```
.promotion-item-img-wrapper__fm {
    width: 100%;
  }

.image-loader__fm {
    height: 464px;
    &::before {
      height: 100%;
      background-size: 400px 104px;
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: -100%;
      bottom: 0;
      left: -100%;
      background-image: linear-gradient(
          to right,
          #ffffff0d 33.3%,
          #ffffff1a,
          #ffffff0d 66.6%
      );
      transform: skewX(-25deg);
      animation: shimmer 7.5s infinite linear;
    }
  }

  @keyframes shimmer {
    0% {
      background-position: -100% 0;
    }
    100% {
      background-position: 100% 0;
    }
  }

.promotion-item_image__fm {
  height: 464px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

The issue I faced is, when src attribute set incorrect it showing alt text and native img icon, but it also has strange white border around it. How can I get rid of that unwanted white border?

I tried border: none; outline: none; and other many tricks but they didn't help me.